# filter by specific category in r

Tags: r, filter

I have a specific filtering question. Here is how my sample dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,3,4,5),
                 cat= c("A","A","A","B","B","B"))
> df
  id cat
1  1     A
2  2     A
3  3     A
4  3     B
5  4     B
6  5     B
```

Grouping by `id`, when the `cat` has multiple categories, I would only filter cat `A`. So the desired output would be:

```
> df.1
  id cat
1  1   A
2  2   A
3  3   A
4  4   B
5  5   B
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only two groups in `cat`, we can use the following logic:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(! (n() == 2 & cat == "B"))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   id [5]
     id cat  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     2 A    
3     3 A    
4     4 B    
5     5 B
```

When there are multiple other letters possible

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,7),
                 cat= c("A","A","A","B","B","B", "A", "B", "C","D"))
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(! (n() >= 2 & cat %in% LETTERS[2:26]))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [7]
     id cat  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     2 A    
3     3 A    
4     4 B    
5     5 B    
6     6 A    
7     7 D
```

**Explanation**: `n()` gives the current group size. When that condition is met, we filter for everything that is not "B".

Comment: thanks for your time and solution!

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can take the first item from the group. In other situations you may need to reorder `arrange` before.

(using `dplyr`)

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(cat = first(cat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
aggregate(
  df$cat, 
  by = list(id = df$id), 
  FUN = \(x) {
    unx <- unique(x)
    if (length(unx) > 1) 'A' else unx
  }
)
#   id x
# 1  1 A
# 2  2 A
# 3  3 A
# 4  4 B
# 5  5 B
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `dplyr`. After grouping by `id`, `filter` where there is only one row per `id` or `cat` is "A".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 | cat == "A")
```

**Output**

```
     id cat  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     2 A    
3     3 A    
4     4 B    
5     5 B
```

Also, if it is possible to have the same `cat` repeated within a single `id`, you can `filter` where the number of distinct `cat` is 1 (or keep if `cat` is "A"):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(cat) == 1 | cat == "A")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
 subset(df, cat == 'A'|id %in% names(which(table(id) == 1)))
  id cat
1  1   A
2  2   A
3  3   A
5  4   B
6  5   B
```